# Setting a fields default value to the result of some calculation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I have 2 entities, let's call them `Parent` and `Child`, with a 1:n relationship, where one `Parent` can have 0-n `Child`.

The `Parent` has two fields, `Parent.Number` and `Parent.Name`. When creating the `Child` via the plus button in a subgrid of `Parent`, the `Child.Name` should be preset to:

> Child of `Parent.Name` (`Parent.Number`)

I've tried lots of different approaches wich all led to dead Ends. Some of them were:

- Calculating via BusinessRules
- Calculated Field on `Child` in combination with BusinessRules
- Calculated Field on `Parent`, transferring the precalculated Text to the `Child` entity by Mapping.
- Calculated Field on `Parent`, using a BusinessRule to set it's value as the default value of `Child.Name`
- Using a workflow for `Child.OnAfterCreate` (works, need it in the `OnFormLoad`, though)

(For brevity I will not go into details of why each approach did not work, but will elaborate on request.)

Is there any way to achieve this without the use of Client side Scripting that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using JavaScript (which is a solution) I can only suggest the following approaches (of which you can use some or all) which are all compromises really:

- Change your requirement to make the name as shown below. A business rule on the child can then be used to populate this information. It can access the `name` but not any other field, i.e. `number`.

> Child of `Parent.Name`

- Use a [quick view form](http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/09/09/exploring-quick-view-forms-in-crm-2013/) to show the `parent` details on the `child`. This allows users to see the data even if the name is not set correctly.
- Use one of the above, and the workflow. So the correct value is still finally set and you provide the user with as much information as possible until that point.
- Remove the name field from the `child` form body. Use a workflow to set the value, when the form is saved. CRM displays names at the top of the form so it will appear as soon as they save but they wont see an empty field before that.
- Change the name of the `parent` record to as shown below, you can then use that in business rules on the `child`.

> `Parent.Name` (`Parent.Number`)

Comment: @JavaScript (which is a solution): It is. I've just spent the last few hours getting myself familiar with Dynamics CRM Scripting and solved the issue. I just wanted to be sure there was no other Option I missed (still fairly new to Dynamics CRM). Thanks for the reply.